# Number of selections of a given element for binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

When I calculate the binomial coefficient, like defined:

$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}$$

How can I determine how often a specific element is selected?
E.g. $\binom{7}{2} = 21$ and each of the seven elements is selected 6 times.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Try to fix the specific one that you are looking at and select one less from the remaining.

Comment: Excuse me, I don't get it, can you give me some more information?

Comment: You have seven balls. You want to look at how many time ball $X$ is selected if you select all combinations of two balls from the $7$ balls. This is equivalent to, you select ball $X$ for sure and then $1$ more other ball. How many selections have you done?

Comment: ahh so it is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, am I wright?

Comment: Yes, you are right.